# Parse/Refactor C# via C# code

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, mono.cecil

Is there any libraries from Microsoft or from Mono project that allow you to do sweeping changes on a C# code base via code? Anything in Cecil for this? I think Cecil would only allow you to work at the bytecode level - anything to work on the language level?

I have already identified the issues I'd like to correct. Just could use some help with the Search/Replace in a C# syntax-aware fashion.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn) - it's only in the preview stage at the moment, but it sounds like just what you want. (There are various blog posts about it, including [this introductory one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx).)

Comment: Sadly the Roslyn CTP is pretty incomplete right now; it doesn't support such key things as events, iterators, initializer expressions, LINQ query syntax, indexers, or anonymous types.  Here's hoping for a new CTP soon.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reasonably powerful search and replace in Resharper if that's appropriate to your situation.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/